# Transactional Publish to Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, transactions

Der all,

I am pondering a problem for some time now and while I do have a conceptual solution, I am not sure, there isn't an easier one especially if there is a library already encapsulating such a solution.

Basically, I want to send a message to Kafka iff a database transaction commits. This message must be reliably stored so that no outage (network or power) can prevent this message from being lost. No XA may be used.

Obviously, out of the blue this is hard. If the transaction to the database is committed prior to sending the message, a number of things can go wrong: power to the application-server can be lost, network connections can break down at most-inconvenient moments and so on. The same is true if the message to Kafka is sent prior to committing the database.

My solution-draft looks like this:

- An additional `event` table is created in the database
- Instead of sending a message to Kafka, the event is stored in this table
- A second process reads from this table and posts messages to Kafka

The second process works in a journal style:

- Read an unsent message, mark this message as `in progress`, commit to DB
- Post message to Kafka
- if not successful: redo, else:
- read message from Kafka
- mark message as `sent`

The trick here would be to re-read messages from Kafka to recover, if a system outage occurs. All messages, which can not be read from Kafka must be considered lost and then re-sent.

No, I assume, I am not the only one who must not lose a message, so I can't imagine this is something which has to be implemented by hand. Am I right?

Comment: We do exactly the same, as we cannot lose any messages, but we deal with duplicates so it's not a problem if we publish a message and then there is failure before we mark it as sent and commit the journal entry. Main other thing to be careful is to ensure you set acks=all on your producer config, else you WILL lose messages sooner or later (I wrote a blog post about it which I can find if you are interested)

Comment: And you are right that the essential problem is that there is no 2-phase commit with kafka and db

Comment: The other approach I have seen which is appropriate in some cases is to publish messages and also consume them, making persistent changes in that consumer on the basis that 'I know the message has been published therefore I can make the DB changes safe in that knowledge. It's the other way round and can be a good approach depending on your application semantics. As with so much in Kafka, there is no single solution.

Comment: @Chris In the end, it all boils down to "do you want at least once or at most once, as 'exactly once' is currently out of stock".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more consulting and thinking this is some kind of XY-Question. What my question originally asked was "how do I implement synchronous semantics with Kafka" - which you shouldn't.

Putting some thought into the business-part of the application, we have not yet found a use case which actually requires the exactly-once semantics. In some cases it is acceptable to lose messages, in other cases we can live with phantom-messages.

If you really have the requirement for exactly-once you will most certainly find, that you have further requirements which scream for syncronous calls like you need an actual confirmation, the action was executed. Do yourself a favour and try not to implement that using a messaging system.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate solution would be to run a CDC kafka connect to stream the data from the database table to the topic. The CDC connectors offer exactly once deliver and you wont face duplicate issues
This also deals with issues arising with 2 phase commits.
The DB acts as the source of truth. The CDC keeps track on the transactional log. even if the connector stops, when restarted it will start from where it failed and eventually sync with the DB state

Comment: Do you mean Debezium and the like? Unfortunately Oracle is only supported with "golden gate", which has a rather "golden price" here. 
Apart: The real question is: does it really work as advertised in any failure scenario?

Comment: @jonathan The solution youre trying to develop is available in kafka itself. You can use Kafka Transactions that essentially does the same thing. You send messages to kafka in a transaction. Once the DB commit is completed you can commit the transaction in kafka.

In case of a failure you abort the transaction in kafka

Please note that you need to configure consumer to read_commited messages only using **isolation.level** property of the consumer.

Comment: Also in case of a failure the 4th step might be troublesome. since the consumer will start consuming from the last committed offset so you might miss some records on restart. and incase of a fresh consumer by default it will start consuming from the latest messages only. also consuming from the start might lead to processing a lot of data from the start of the topic

Comment: I don't think that kafka transactions solve my issue. The commit of the Kafka-TX und the DB-TX are still two non-atomic-method-calls. Should an outage occure between both steps, one of the commits will be missing.